# How to get notified about Android system theme change?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, themes

Android introduced Dark Theme in API level 29 and higher (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme). To support Dark Theme in your own app your app's theme needs to inherit from DayNight theme. 
But what if you did your own theming, is there any intent from Android to get noticed about the system theme change?

Answer (score 13):

If you add `android:configChanges="uiMode"` to your activities in the manifest, when the user changes the theme, the `onConfigurationChanged` method is called. If you override that you can do all the related work in there. In order to check what the current theme is you can do the following:

```
val currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
when (currentNightMode) {
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {} // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {} // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
}
```

EDIT: Since the original question isn't specific to Kotlin, here is the Java version of the above for reference:

```
int currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
        break;
}
```

([source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#kotlin))